# Moodle: Where am I likely to find this CSS stylesheet?

Tags: css, moodle

I want to change a CSS property of the question plugin (basically want to change the question's `.que .content {margin: 0 0 0 8.5em;}` to `.que .content {margin: 0 0 0 0;}`).

I figured out this line of code and the change I want to make in the built-in developer tools of FireFox browser. The Web-Developer Tools shows this line of code to be present in:

**`http://localhost/moodle/theme/styles_debug.php?theme=genesis&type=parent&subtype=canvas&sheet=question`**

Now, styles_debug.php is a .php file. It does not contain any styling information (except that it has been passed $sheet as an optional parameter).

So where can I find this actual stylesheet?

Has anyone faced this kinda problem in trying to change some Moodle core CSS. Any help for me? Thank you.

Comment: Show us the demo site. How can we help without having look at it???

Comment: @Richa It's on my local web server. Is there a way to show it to you? Secondly, what kinda additional information do you need to help? I am not sure how will looking at the site tell you where the file might be located?

Comment: I guess there are site o which you can host it temporarily. Developer tool will give an idea about where the file is located.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer may be in the URL you're giving.

I can't look into this Genesis theme because it isn't free, but I guess this CSS markup is located into **moodle/theme/canvas/style/question.css**

- `localhost/moodle/theme/` gives you the path to the theme directory
- `theme=genesis` gives you the information about the current theme
- `subtype=canvas` means Genesis is using the Canvas' theme stylesheet named `question.css`

Comment: I had also thought that way but no, the `style` directory in the theme does not have a `question.css`, I have no idea where that sheet might be.

Comment: Ok, I know where it is located. You will find it into moodle/theme/canvas/style/question.css

Comment: Woah! This is correct. `Genesis` extends `canvas`, and I had looked up everywhere but this did not come to my mind. Thank you. You can edit your answer and write it clearly. Then I can accept the answer.